# regex for URL starting with http/https or www

Tags: asp.net, regex

The user should be able to write it in any of the below formats

http://www.microsoft.com
or
https://www.microsoft.com
or 
www.microsoft.com

Programming Language : C#

Comment: Who says the subdomain must be `www`? What have you tried so far? What programming language are you using?

Comment: (http + https + <null>)E*.E*.E* in language-agnostic regular expression notation... Could replace the first E* with www... E is the set of all legal symbols for a URL.

Comment: I'm using asp.net and i need to validate the URL entered in a text box

Comment: Validate... against what? Any valid URL? Specific websites? Specific pages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work for most regex processors:

```
/((?:https?\:\/\/|www\.)(?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)*[-a-z0-9]+.*)/i
```

What this matches:

- Anything that starts with `http://`, `https://`, or `www.`
- Followed by at least one or more valid domain characters (a-z, 0-9, or -)
- Matches without case sensitivity (`/i`)
- It does *not* enforce white space, so it **will** match this: `blahwww.domain.com`, and return `www.domain.com`  If you want to enforce space, add `\s` to the beginning, but then you have to ensure that you add a space to the beginning of the string to match.

The `(?:)` blocks are non-matching groups.  They prevent those specific groups of characters from being assigned a number.  They can be replaced with matching groups `()` if your regex processor has trouble.  Group 1 is always the entire URL.

It's not terribly strict, but it matches all standard domain names (but might let slip through some invalid ones).

Also, next time, you might want to include the programming language or context, because regex processors vary greatly in feature support.

Comment: I just tried it, and it did work.  I'm not sure what else to tell you, your question was pretty vague, as is your comment.

Comment: The problem lies probably in the delimiting slashes which are used in JavaScript but not in .NET regexes. I agree about the OP's vagueness, though. You might want to add anchors to your regex, too. And remove the unnecessary backslashes.

Comment: you can add spaces :|

Answer (score 1):

Without using  `http | https | fts`:

```
Var url = /^((www|WWW)\.){1}?([a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)$/;
```

using  `http | https | fts`:

```
var url = /^((http|ftp|https):\/\/|((www|WWW)\.)){1}?([a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-  9]+)+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)$/;
```